# Best JavaFx container for manipulating long strings char by char

Tags: javafx, jtable, tableview

I'm working with DNA data, in it's simplest form a name/id with sequence info:

```
public class FastaSequence {
    private String name;
    private String sequence;    
{
```

The `sequence` is basically ATGGCTATCAC... for a few thousand chars long. I also have several hundred of these things to compare at any one time.

I need to be able to manipulate the chars in columns and cells, e.g. select the 125th char of each aligned sequence, in a GUI like JavaFX, so I was thinking to use `TableView` and convert the `sequence` to a list of chars and feed it to the table model as such. That way each char would get it's own column and I could like color all the T containing cells in red etc.

I have tried this with Python's TableView and I get a working prototype, but it's very slow to respond (loading a list, refreshing), even with a list of only a hundred sequences loaded. So my question is two-fold:

1) Will the JavaFX implementation be (a lot) faster than Python, even when loading a 100k or more cells?

2) Am I barking up the wrong tree and is there a better way to view/manipulate the data as I described it above? Should I be using another model?

**UPDATE**

I have been doing more research on this and found that the TableView in JavaFX is apparently not designed for huge numbers of columns: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udc2iRZBF0M at 1:51.

So I went back to testing a JTable in Swing. Without further fluff it gives me a responsive (i.e. easy to scroll) table upto about a 1000 lines of a 1000 chars. However, making the TableModel a little more complex and using custom cell renderers to center chars in the cell and remove cell borders and such destroys the responsiveness. Because of the many things I've tried I'm not posting all the code here. If/when I come closer to a solution I'll update with my minimal (working?) code. Maybe I need to go back a simpler control like a custom class based on a grid based layout, without the overhead of the JTable and it's model?

Comment: Your question is likely too broad for Stack Overflow. You should prototype in both languages and profile to see which is more performant. A JavaFX `TableView` is a "virtual" control, which means it only renders enough cells needed to fill the available visible space (at least row wise, having many columns will cause issues). If Python's equivalent control doesn't do the same then JavaFX will be likely be better in this aspect.

Comment: If you end up staying with JavaFX, you might want to look into the [ControlsFX](https://github.com/controlsfx/controlsfx) library; specifically, their [`GridView`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html) control or, if necessary, their [`SpreadsheetView`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html) control. The library has releases for JavaFX 8, JavaFX 9, and it appears a release candidate for JavaFX 11+.

Comment: @Slaw: Thanks for the comment, I'll definitely check out the `GridView`, I suppose it will have less overhead than the `SpreadsheetView`? As the `JTable` is more or less working for not too large sets, the first pressure now is going to be on getting a working prototype out. Maybe I should close my -1 rated question in the meantime...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to make an array of all the characters in a string:

```
String sequence = "ATGGCTATCAC";
char[] chars = sequence.toCharArray();
```

And then you can use `System.out.println(chars[125]);` to print out the 125th char in that sequence.

I've never used tables in JavaFX before, but I think you can do something like this:

```
TableColumn column = new TableColumn("Letter");
table.getColumns().add(column);

root.getChildren.add(table);

ObservableList<Character> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    data.add(chars[i]);
}

table.setItems(data);
```

Comment: not having used a control ever (not even before posting a code snippet in an answer) is rarely a good idea - and it isn't here: apart from other problems (like f.i. that very convoluted way to fill the observableList) your table won't show anything

Comment: @ Superhuman: Thanks for the input, but I know how to package my data. The trouble is a little more high level, i.e. getting the data into a graphical view/control (preferably using Java) that is still responsive enough to easily scroll and select ranges of cells or columns for my use-case. Ideally I can move my data around a bit and annotate it without it feeling like a walk through a swamp...